# How to find the maximum and minimum values of $\frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$ algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The function is $f(x) = \frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$.
I have tried using calculus, only to fail.

Comment: Start by finding the derivative $$f'(x) = \frac{16 x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\frac{32 \left(x^2-1\right) x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}+\frac{8 \left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$ and set it equal to zero to find the critical points $$\left(-1-\sqrt{2},1-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}+1\right)$$

Comment: How did you find the critical points without using a calculator @Moo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice challenge. The range of such function is made by the real numbers $k$ such that
$$ \frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2} = k $$
has at least a real solution. The previous equation is equivalent to
$$ k x^4 - 8x^3 + 2kx^2 +8x + k = 0$$
and the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of the LHS equals $2^{16}(k^2-4)^2$.
 It follows that the range of the given function is the interval $[-2,2]$.

---

**Fun fact**: by substituting $x=\tan\theta$ the given expression turns into $-2\sin(4\theta)$ and the whole problem becomes trivial. Does *trigonometry* count as *algebra*?

Comment: How did you find the discriminant of a fourth degree equation? I have been  introduced only to the discriminant of a quadratic equation.

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam: in the quadratic case the discriminant is given by $(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2$ where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are the roots of the given polynomial. In the quartic case (please see the linked page) the discriminant is defined as $\prod_{1\leq i < j\leq 4}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2$, but it still is a symmetric function of the roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$ which can be computed from the coefficients of the given polynomial.

Comment: Trignometry answers are appreciated too.

Comment: if you don't mind, could just reiterate the definition of a discriminant for me. I am asking because I haven't learnt this, "in the quadratic case the discriminant is given by (α1−α2)2(α1−α2)2 where α1,α2α1,α2 are the roots of the given polynomial".

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Expression_in_terms_of_the_roots

Answer (score 4):

HINT: prove that $$-2\le \frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}\le 2$$
we have $$2-\frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}=2\,{\frac { \left( {x}^{2}-2\,x-1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and $$2+\frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}=2\,{\frac { \left( {x}^{2}+2\,x-1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
the Minimum will be attained by $$x=-1-\sqrt{2}$$ and the Maximum by $$1-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: I have arrived at this inequality by plotting it on a graph. Anyway, I will try once more to prove it.

Comment: Could you just give me another clue?

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, but how do you guess the inequality in the first place without a graph?

Comment: i have used my calculator from the school

Comment: Well, our exams don't allow calculators.

Comment: then you can plot your function pointwise

Comment: Umm.. isn't that time consuming? Yeah, it is possible to solve it in that manner within five minutes but in an exam where seconds count, how do I solve this mathematically?

Comment: to correct finish the proof you  should prove that these bounds can be reached

Comment: i have added these terms

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b$ is in the range of the given function. Then equation
$$ \frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2} = b $$

$$ \frac{8x^2(x-{1\over x})}{x^2(x+{1\over x})^2} = b $$
Mark $t =  x-{1\over x}$ and $t$ takes all real values. Then we have 
$$ b= \frac{8t}{t^2+4} $$ If $t$ is positive then $b\leq 2$ since $4t\leq t^2+4$ or $(t-2)^2\geq 0$ is true. If $t$ is negative then $b\geq -2$. So the range is $[-2,2]$ since $b(t)$ is continious function.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{8x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2}={8(x^3-x)}{(x^2+1)^{-2}}\\f'(x)=8\left(\left(x^3-x\right)\left(-\dfrac{4x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}\right)+\left(3x^2-1\right){(x^2+1)^{-2}}\right)\\=
8\left(-\dfrac{4x^4-4x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}+\frac{3x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^{2}}\right)
\\=
8\left(\dfrac{4x^2-4x^4}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}+\frac{(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)^{2}(x^2+1)}\right)
\\=
8\left(\dfrac{4x^2-4x^4+(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}\right)
\\=
\frac{-8 (x^4 - 6 x^2 + 1)}{(x^2 + 1)^3}$$
now just solve for $0=x^4 - 6 x^2 + 1$

$$0=x^4 - 6 x^2 + 1,u=x^2\\0=u^2-6u+1\\u_{1,2}={\frac  {6\pm {\sqrt  {36-4\ }}}{2}}=\begin{cases}3+2\sqrt2\\3-2\sqrt2\end{cases}$$

so you get $4$ answers:$$x_{1,2,3,4}=\begin{cases}\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}&=&1+\sqrt2\\[2ex]
-\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}&=&-1-\sqrt2\\[2ex]
\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}&=&\sqrt2-1\\[2ex]
-\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}&=&1-\sqrt2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hey, I also posted this question on Yahoo Answers, and I got a simplified version of your answer over there. Check it out. [Yahoo Answers](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20171021171056AA8HZMb)

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam i understand that way but i really hate to remember few different ways to solve things so i went this way. normally i would apply $\ln$ on both sides and this will get me to what the one in yahoo done but i assume that he didnt learn that so i stayed with this way

Comment: Do you have an algebraic solution to this? It would be appreciated.

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam i added it

Comment: when I said algebraic solution, I meant an algebraic proof for the entire question. Not just the last part about getting the roots of the biquadratic equation.